# can't install grunt-contrib-imagemin using git bash

Tags: gruntjs, git-bash, image-compression

when i'm typing this line in the git bash

npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin --save-dev

i get this errors

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'C:\Users\hussa\package.json'
C:\Users\hussa

`-- grunt-contrib-imagemin@1.0.1

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hussa\package.json'

npm WARN hussa No description

npm WARN hussa No repository field.

npm WARN hussa No README data

npm WARN hussa No license field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling `npm` to update your package.json file with the new dependency when using the `--save-dev` flags

Looks like you dont have a package.json file in your current directory. In which case you can create one with `npm init` and then rerun the `npm install` command after it is created.

If you do have a package.json file check you have permissions to edit and ensure it is not corrupt.